# How do I programatically create a new Google Analytics session/visitor in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, single-page-application

I have an SPA that is running on a public computer.  The app resets after a period of inactivity, and I would like any analytics that occur after the reset to show up as a different session/user.  How can I do this?

I have tried deleting the __utm cookies (leaving __utmv), and further calls do show up as a different user, but I lose my custom variables for the first tracked event, whether I reset them right after deleting the cookie or right before tracking the next event.

Comment: I assume you've already tried creating another cookie storing the custom variable data?

Comment: Switch to Universal Analytics (you will have to, eventually) and set the session timeout to match the session timeout for your application.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871?hl=en

Comment: @EikePierstorff All user activity doesn't generate analytic events, but it will reset our inactivity timer.  There are also a few actions that cause the app to reset right away.

Comment: I discussed the only way I can think of to programmatically restart a session here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553492/in-google-analytics-the-custom-variables-get-overwritten-for-multiple-user-roles/19566388#19566388 - but in effect I'd say the answer is simply "you can't". Maybe you should really look into Universal Analytics and try to convert your custom vars to custom metrics and dimensions (which are stored serverside , not in cookies). However unlike with custom  vars there is no way to retrieve the values via code.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like switching to Universal and sending a [`sessionControl: 'start'`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sessionControl) field is the best I'll get.

Comment: It would be wonderful if you could eventually drop a small comment here if this actually works as expected in a production site.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, sending an event with `sessionControl: 'start'` causes a new visit in analytics - I couldn't get it to count as a new unique user.  That said, the new visit should give me the granularity I need.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for the answer to this in the future, here's how I've been able to achieve it...

```
// set the analytics session and visitor timeout to 10 milliseconds
_gaq.push(['_setSessionCookieTimeout', 10]);
_gaq.push(['_setVisitorCookieTimeout', 10]);
// make a fake page view, 10 milliseconds after this, the session will time out
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/session/reset/']);

// after a short delay, set the analytics session and visitor timeout to 5 minutes,
// this should start a new session
setTimeout(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_setSessionCookieTimeout', 300000]); // 5 minutes * 60 * 1000 = 300000
    _gaq.push(['_setVisitorCookieTimeout', 300000]);
    // log a page view...
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/some/page/url/']);
}, 200);
```

... I'm not sure if that second page view is necessary or not (I needed it for my solution), but the cookie timeout updates seem to trigger a new session and visitor id

Also you might want to set the new timeout value to more than 5 minutes (the default is 30 minutes, or 1800000 milliseconds)